# How to interact Query and Mutation in Apollo-client using React

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I am learning Apollo and react-hook. I am trying write a little demo which just input a name and render it below. All data is query and mutate through Apollo-server.

Now Apollo-server is work right. But any time I input a new name, I have to refresh the page. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf32O.gif)
I should set the state in react, but I don't know how to set it properly in react.

Here is code:

`App.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import ShowChannel from './ShowChannel';
import AddChannel from './AddChannel';

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <AddChannel></AddChannel>
            <ShowChannel></ShowChannel>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

`ShowChannel.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

const QUERY_CLIENT = gql`
    query {
        channels {
            id
            name
        }
    }
`;

export default function ShowChannel() {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(QUERY_CLIENT);

    if (loading) return 'Loading...';
    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    data.channels.map((channel) => (
                        <li key={channel.id}> {channel.id}: {channel.name}</li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`AddChannel.js`

```
import React from 'react';

import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

const ADD_CHANNEL = gql`
    mutation ($name: String!){
        addChannel(name: $name){
            id
            name
        }
    }
`;

const AddChannel = () => {
    let input;
    const [addChannel, { data }] = useMutation(ADD_CHANNEL);
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                addChannel({ variables: { name: input.value } });
                input.value = '';
            }}>
                <input
                    ref={node => {
                        input = node;
                    }}
                />
                <button type="submit">add channel</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AddChannel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to keep your data and your UI in sync.

1. Calling `refetch` after your mutation. Read more [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#refetching)
2. Using `update` props of your `useMutation` to update your cache after your mutation. Read more [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#updating-the-cache-after-a-mutation)
3. Using [`Subscription`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/) to keep data in sync over cross platforms.